# How to prevent a child form to inherit the Alphablend Property of the Parent Form?

Tags: api, delphi, vcl

I create a form (Form1) that I am using as a background form. I set its AlphaBlend property to True and set its AlphaBlendValue to 230, making the form transparent.

I then create a second, totally independent, form (Form2) with its AlphaBlend property to False (I even implicitly set this when creating the form). I then set Form1 as the parent window of Form2 (via Form2.Parent = Form1).

This makes the child window take on the parent windows AlphaBlend Properties which then cant be independently changed. I am unable to modify the Alpha properties on Form2 at all.

I require Form2 to be a child of Form1 but cant have the Alpha properties inherited.

Comment: For windows version 7 and below, you will not be able to do this. This limited by OS

Comment: I think that this issue has no relation with OS because I have tested the same method in VB and it's work without problems maybe in c# will work too but with Delphi it's maybe need a new class or a special component...

Comment: What makes you so sure that the Delphi implementation is based on the same winapi functionality as your vb code?

Comment: `I think that this issue has no relation with OS`. Delphi controls is simple wrapper on winapi controls.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity ... but my comment talk about the method how VB code work than mine in delphi and not about the API itself (even the Api is different doesn't make sense if the form itself in VB and Delphi was totally different.... ) finally with best regards and any suggestions is well appreciated.

Comment: @Bravesaw A VCL Form's `AlphaBlend` and `TransparentColor` features are based on the `WS_EX_LAYERED` window style. Prior to Windows 8, a *child* window cannot have the `WS_EX_LAYERED` window style applied to it. That is what Vasek is referring to. IIRC, WFC in .NET uses window-less UI controls (similar to Delphi's FireMonkey), so would not be affected by this.

Comment: May I know which solution that exactly can fix this issue?  Without changing the vcl with firemonkey of course...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can consider another approach: do not set the parent of the "embedded" form, but keep it separate. Instead handle message `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` of `Form1` and set `Form2` position relative to `ClientOrigin` of `Form1`:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    procedure WindowPosChanging(var Msg : TMessage); message WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING;
  public
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit2;

procedure TForm1.WindowPosChanging(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if Assigned(Form2) then
  begin
    Form2.Left := ClientOrigin.X + 20;
    Form2.Top := ClientOrigin.Y + 10;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Looking closely, one can see that the second form is lagging a pixel or so in following the movement of the first form, shouldn't bee too disturbing.

Comment: But if I clicked on the main form the child form hide behind the form1 ? Maybe setforground Api can fix that with some hooks codes....

Comment: Did you try, or are you just speculating? In my test `Form2` stays in front.  Perhaps you should also say which Delphi version you are using and which OS's you are targeting.

Comment: To be sincerely I didn't try this yet ( I'm out of my house now)  but I remember that I was programmed a shadow form for my forms by this technique and using this api above...  I think I'm wrong while i didn't try it yet...

Comment: Its hide behind the Main form when I resize the main form after I was add this inside windoposchanging procedure : Form2. Width := (form1. Width) - 40, form2. Height := (form1. Height) - 20,

Comment: @Bravesaw You must be doing something different from what I have done. Resizing the form1 does not hide the form2 behind form1. **I repeat my question from a previous comment: Which Delphi version, which OS?**

Comment: Delphi Berlin update 2 and windows 10 version 1709 version OS 16299.371

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will check later in a similar setup. Now I use Delphi XE7 and Win 7. After adding your width and height setting code to my previous code, form2 still is in front of form1. Did you change anything else?

Comment: I use bsnone for the both forms and I resize the main form with my own code.

Comment: This is now evolving to a never ending story, when you drop additional info one by one. As what you asked about can't be realized (In Win7 and earlier), I gave you a possible workaround for your question. If that doesn't work for you, it's ok to leave it as such. You can ask a new question how to use the workaround in your specific case, with all constraints, requirements and other details explained in that question.

Comment: OK I will try to fix this problem and if is perfect I will post it here and many thanks for your help and your respectable effort here...

Answer (score 0):

OK I have changed my source code to get fix the issue on the WS_EX_LAYERED Window form by adding two forms on the main app one of them is alphablend true with 200 value as a background and the second is normal as the front window while the main App is totally transparent with the property transparent color and here is the link of my first beta solution https://1drv.ms/u/s!Alu0WnpJr3ruhTB68XOMcpd3mB5u

Finally I have  a little issue with the background form that can't be a container for any controls or even the hit test doesn't work on it....  I hope to accept my idea even has not complete yet....